# Which Event Handler is called while adding items to the DataTable of a ComboBox at run time?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have added the items to the DataTable of a ComboBox at run time by clicking a button.
I have set `MaxDropDownItems = 6` on a `button_Click` event.

When I got the result, only 2 items are shown with ScrollBar.
What to do to get 6 items in the DropDown using `MaxDropDownItems`.

Expected: DropDown with 6 items

Code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
private DataTable GetDataTable() 
{ 
    DataColumn col = new DataColumn("tt", typeof(string)); 
    dt.Columns.Add(col); 
    col = new DataColumn("nn", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add(col);
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    { 
        System.Data.DataRow row = dt.NewRow(); 
        row[0] = j + ""; 
        row[1] = j + ""; 
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    return dt; 
 }
```

Then in `button_Click`:

```
if (i == 0) 
{
    combobox.DataSource = GetDataTable();
    combobox.MaxDropDownItems = 6; 
}
else 
{
    System.Data.DataRow row = dt.NewRow(); 
    row[0] = i + ""; 
    row[1] = i + "";
    dt.Rows.Add(row); 
    combobox.DataSource = dt; 
 } 

 i++;
 combobox.Refresh();
```

Comment: Can you share more info? What's in the data table? What else do you have in the `button_Click` event?

Comment: The question title seems to be completely different than the question itself. What is the relevant code? What do you mean by "*custom*" combobox?

Comment: How have you associated the DataTable and the ComboBox? Are you updating the DataTable after you have set it as the `ComboBox.DataSource`? (I assume you have checked that your DataTable doesn't contain just two rows). Posting a sample of the code used - related to the question - is always a good idea.

Comment: I have created one method using DataTable.In that I have created a new row of values using for loop.  In button click I have display and value member and assigned my datatable method to data source and set the maxdropdownitem=6

Comment: I have associated the combobox and button.When I click the button GetDataTable method  of the type DataTable will be triggered.In that I have added the row of values using System.Data.DataRow row = dt.NewRow(); In button_Click event I have maxdropdownitems=6 and display,value members.

Comment: @Jimi I have updated a code for your reference.Please suggest a solution

Comment: This code should add two items to you ComboBox the first time you create a DataTable, then a new item when the Button is clicked (if `i != 0`, that is, otherwise the same 2 rows). Change this (and siblings): `row[0] = i + "";` to `row[0] = i.ToString();` (C# != VB.Net). You also don't need this: `combobox.DataSource = dt;`: when you add rows to your DataTable, the update is automatically propagated.

Comment: Thanks@jimi.By doing like above solution I can't get the maxdropdown item 6.Is there any event handler available while adding items into datasource?